# How does Telegram make use of iCloud?

Tags: ios, icloud, data-synchronization

This is strange that I find Telegram, Sketchbook and some other music streaming apps having an option to be syned with iCloud. For applications like Photos, once it gets synced with iCloud, it is available on your Mac (or the website version of iClouds). In the case of Sketchbook, I feel like it creates an account in some form, or creates an iCloud folder (not visible directly) where the image gallery is stored.

What about Telegram? It has the sync option in Settings > [name] > iClouds, among other applications. This is weird since Telegram uses its own server and cloud storage.

Comment: Is this question about how apps can use iCloud storage or about how Telegram uses it? And if it about Telegram, based on what do you assume it uses iCloud at all?

Comment: @nohillside I have edited it. I see an option in the iCloud sync. I found it strange, which is why I posted it.